# How to setup a new NestJs Project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, nestjs

Trying to get [Nest JS](https://docs.nestjs.com/) running for a new project.

Have run the following 'getting started guide'

```
$ git clone https://github.com/nestjs/nest-typescript-starter.git project
$ cd project
$ npm install
$ npm run start
```

but when I open http://localhost:3000 I get the error `Cannot GET /`

Is this normal or do I need to add components or modules before anything actually runs?

I find the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/first-steps) don't actually explain what to do after cloning and installing packages...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey could you please checkout the 
https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/105

Comment: I did see that issue but I am not getting the error `Cannot find module 'ts-node/register'`

Comment: Looks like it doesn't come bootstrapped so you need to add controllers and components but the documentation appears to be incomplete. It suggests `There's a Cat interface here.` but fails to provide a link. Similarly for `CreateCatDto`

Comment: Example boilerplate project that might be helpful https://github.com/kentloog/nestjs-sequelize-typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually cloning Nest-js repo dosen't allow you to start immediatly, is just composed of examples that you can run.

But you can find some repo's to start, which help you, on the following link : https://github.com/juliandavidmr/awesome-nest 
This repo provide some link to have many information in different way to use Nest-js

Have a great day !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `npm run start:dev` to run it in developer mode